# How to split string that is a part of a tuple list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of string tuples (list[tuple[str, str]]) like this `[('JimKing', 'TheKing'), ('GadgetKing', 'EnergyKing'), ('ThingKing', 'Energyking')]` and I would like to split and print the first string in the tuples eg `list[0] = 'JimKing'`
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Do you mean like `first, second = zip(*lst_of_tuples)`?

Comment: If you want a new list with only the first entry of all tuples in your original list (your question isn't quite clear to me) you can loop over the list elements, take the first entry in the tuples and put that in a new list. With a list comprehension that's a one-liner. (Edit: I like the version from @tobias_k but a more explicit approach isn't bad either.)

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is a more pythonic way of doing this but the following works:

```
for pair in my_list:
   print(pair[0])
```